# How to get a resource file from a project in the Qt Creator?

Tags: 12.04, qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator 2.7.2 'Based on Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit)'. For some examples, I get  *.pro, *.h and *.cpp files. It appears that if I want to use the Design mode, I need to have a resource *.ui file. Is it possible to get the *.ui file from such a project? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can do without the conversion I have asked about. For my learning Qt Creator and Qt Designer, I think that the samples having *.ui files are enough for what I need.